# How to control torque effects on the ground?

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm building a Lippisch ground effect vehicle with it's wingtips almost touching the ground, but because of torque effects the left wing actually does touch the ground, so it can't lift off. It even can't go straight.
Adding ailerons isn't an option because this problem has to be solved on te ground (zero speed) and not in the air (because it doesn't get there).
Does someone know something how I can solve this problem?

Comment: In what way is torque affecting things?

Comment: It is actually the reaction of the spinning propeller and motor who causes this problem

Comment: Is a contra-rotating propellor an option?

Comment: Where do you have to place it then?

Comment: right in front of it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra-rotating_propellers

Comment: I have this motor: https://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__14398__Turnigy_Park300_Brushless_Outrunner_1380kv.html
How can I manage to make the second propeller spin in the opposite direction of the first one, when I connect this two propellers with the same motor?

Comment: Now you're getting into small scale engineering, and out of the scope of the SE site, but I would have thought a bit of gearing would get you where you need to be

Comment: can't you put low-friction skids under the wingtips? and maybe even launch off a low-friction surface?

Answer (score 7):

[The Lockheed U2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2) had the same problem (bicycle wheel base and they had to prevent one end being dragged on takeoff).

They solved it by adding "pogo wheels" that self detach on take off. (the ones on the orange sticks.)

[image]
(source [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:U-_2A_Dragon_Lady_at_USAF_Museum.jpg))

Answer (score 3):

The commenters are right: Either use two separate propellers (left and right) which turn in opposite direction, or use a counter-rotating prop.

[image]

This picture of a P-38 shows the principle. You can drive both props from the same engine by using driveshafts or belts. The Wright flyer had such an arrangement.

[image]

On small airplanes with very big engines a gearbox with concentric driveshafts is driving both propellers in opposite direction.

[image]

A simpler way to have contra-rotating props is to put them at opposite ends of an engine pod.

In all cases the prop torque is reduced to zero, or in case of the podded arrangement, almost zero.